# How to send HTML formatted data in Json

Tags: javascript, html, json, web, encoding

In one of application I'm working on user can send message from Web client to Mobile client.

There in Web client when user copy from other Source which contain HTML Tag(like Hyperlink), it copied as it is and display as HTML text content. But same when it received from web to Mobile client, it's display as plain text data.

What could be way to display same HTML text content to mobile client also.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlElement = document.querySelector('html');

//for post send
var postObject = {
   formatedHtml:htmlElement.innerHTML
}

$.post('http://blabla.com', postObject);
//or
$.post('http://blabla.com', JSON.stringify(postObject));

//for get send
var queryString = encodeURIComponent(htmlElement.innerHTML)

$.get('http://blabla.com', queryString);
```

**String html text to html bind**

```
document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = formatedHTMLString
```